# MVC Unit Testing Controller Method with FormCollection argument

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am having a controller method which accepts FormCollection as a parameter.
the controller method then builds the model using UpdateModel(Model, new[] { P1, P2 });

I would like to unit test the above method. I am populating the formcollection with P1 and P2 values but the model is not build correctly when called from unit testing.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 3):

The `UpdateModel` method looks in the `Request` object when populating the model and it completely ignores this `FormCollection` you are passing. So you will need to mock the request and add the values to this object. But thats lots of work that isn't worth the efforts and I would recommend you a better way: instead of using `FormCollection` as action parameter and then calling `UpdateModel` inside your action use a strongly typed action parameter:

```
public ActionResult Foo(SomeViewModel model)
{
    // The model binder will automatically call UpdateModel and populate
    // the model from the request so that you don't need to manually
    // do all this stuff
    ...
}
```

and in the unit test simply pass the desired model when invoking the controller action.

Comment: Even I prefer the model approach but my manager says what if some one tampers and  modifies the request. Using UpdateModel we have control, when building the model. Not surer how to convince "THE MANAGER"

Comment: @Snehal, you should use view models. Those are classes which are specifically tailored to the needs of the view. Those classes contain only the properties you need to be bound from the view. So you have full control. It's a much cleaner approach than using `FormCollection`. Your manager should read more about ASP.NET MVC :-). Also there's the [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx) allowing you to select which properties should be included or excluded from binding but honestly if you use view models you will never have any problems.